# redis-cli FLUSHALL and FLUSHDB return ok but do nothing after Hubot restores redis

Tags: redis, node-redis, hubot

On ubuntu 16.04. Interacting with a local redis instance via redis-cli. Working with a node hubot script which uses redis as its primary data store.

when I type `keys *` I get a single key `hubot:storage`

so I `FLUSHALL` and get an `ok` response. But if the Hubot is running or else as soon as it turns on, it restores the value of that key immediately so I can never delete it.

I'v used the `info` command to try to see if it is persisting on some other redis instance and I've cleared all backup files from `/var/redis`. Basically I can't figure out where this data is being stored to keep getting restored from.

Any advice regarding how I could clear this out or where Hubot may be caching this?

It seems to be related to this code: https://github.com/hubotio/hubot-redis-brain/blob/master/src/redis-brain.js  specifically the chunk at line 49 is what gets called before each restore.

Comment: You have 2 choices: First stop using hubot and second stop delete keys

Comment: flushall just delete everything after the command is triggered after that every writes will be processed as usual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps

1. Stop hubot
2. Flush redis (important that this is done while hubot is NOT running)
3. Start hubot

The reasoning is that hubot has an in-memory representation of the brain and will write it out to redis at intervals.  Perhaps a nicer solution to this which would help during script development would be a command that can empty the brain and save that, but I can't see an obvious API for that in either `robot.brain` or `hubot-redis-brain`